# How can I get AWS credentials using a SAML token?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

What I am trying to do: Authenticate my users using ADFS, pass the SAML response token to AWS and get back credentials which I can then use to access AWS resources.

What I am able to do now: Sign in successfully through ADFS and get the SAML token back which confirms the successfully sign in.

What is not working: Calling the AWS.STS.assumeRoleWithSaml functions gets a 403 Access Denied error

How it works thus far:

1. Users click a button on my application, which calls the following:

   ```
   var RPID = encodeURIComponent('urn:amazon:webservices');
   var result = 'https://virtualMachine.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com/adfs/ls/IdpInitiatedSignOn.aspx?loginToRp=' + RPID;
   window.location.href = result;
   ```
2. A successful sign in here returns back to the application a SAML response token

   ```
   var saml = new URL(window.location.href);
   var token = saml.searchParams.get('SAMLResponse');
   ```
3. The application then calls assumeRoleWithSAML to get back credentials. The Principal ARN refers to the identity provider I am trying to access and the RoleARN refers to a role which has full access to everything:

   ```
   authenticateSAMLwithCognito(token) {
   //define our security token service object
   var sts = new AWS.STS();
   //build our parameter object
   var params = {
       //cognito identity provider
       PrincipalArn: 'arn:aws:iam::accountid:saml-provider/wmpo-adfs',
       //role assuming
       RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::accountid:role/ADFS-Dev',
       //authorization
       SAMLAssertion: token
   }

   console.log("Parameters sent", params);
   sts.assumeRoleWithSAML(params, (err, data) => {

       if(err) console.log(err);
       else console.log("Success!", data);
   })
   }
   ```

However the response from this exchange is:

[image: error message]

I am really unsure why this is, but if anyone has some helpful pushes that would be great! Thanks and happy new year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow that only took days, but though I was constantly stumbling, I finally made it to the point I was trying to get.

The answer was in the same credentials get function that I used when I authenticated users through a username password combo by way of a Cognito User Pool.

```
    authenticateThroughCognito(token) {
      AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
          IdentityPoolId: 'us-west-2:IdentityPoolId',
          Logins: {
              'arn:aws:iam::accountId:saml-provider/wmpo-adfs' : token
          }
      });

      (AWS.config.credentials as AWS.Credentials).get((err) => {
          if(err) console.log(err);
          else {
              console.log("Success");
              console.log(AWS.config.credentials);
          }
      })
    }
```